# Execution of Quarts scheduler in Spring MVC multiple times

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, quartz-scheduler, scheduling

I am using Quarts for task scheduling in [Spring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spring_Framework) MVC, and my problem is that it executes multiple times (twice) every task. Please find the configuration and Java files below.

#### File web.xml

```
<!--  Spring Configuration -->

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>

<listener>
  <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

#### File spring-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/task
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="e24online.corporate.springmvc.controllers" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.elitecore.dashboard.controller" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="e24online.corporate.zeroconfiguration.controllers" />

    <import resource="serviceConf.xml" />
    <import resource="daoConf.xml" />
    <import resource="beanConf.xml" />
    <import resource="spring-quartz.xml" />

    <bean id="jspViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/webpages/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="messageSource" class="e24online.corporate.springmvc.E24onlineReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="classpath:resources/properties/menu" />
        <property name="basenames">
            <list>
                <value>file:/usr/local/cyberoam/properties/multilingual/menu</value>
                <value>file:/usr/local/cyberoam/properties/multilingual/label</value>
                <value>file:/usr/local/cyberoam/properties/multilingual/message</value>
                <value>file:/usr/local/cyberoam/properties/multilingual/misc</value>
                <value>file:/usr/local/cyberoam/properties/multilingual/javascript</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="cacheSeconds" value="3000" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="localeChangeInterceptor" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
        <property name="paramName" value="lang" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="localeResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver">
        <property name="defaultLocale" value="en" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Configure the multipart resolver -->
    <bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
        <!-- one of the properties available; the maximum file size in bytes -->
        <property name="maxUploadSize" value="524288000"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="handlerMapping"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping">
        <property name="interceptors">
        <list>
            <ref bean="localeChangeInterceptor" />
            <bean class="e24online.corporate.springmvc.intercepter.E24onlineInterceptor"/>
        </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

#### File spring-quartz.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

    <bean id="myTask" class="e24online.corporate.cas.printer.testScheduler.FixedDelayWorker" />

    <!-- Specifing class and method that is going to be called on a specified
         time basis. -->
    <bean id="myJob"
        class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean">
        <property name="targetObject" ref="myTask" />
        <property name="targetMethod" value="work" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Simple trigger specify repeat interval and delay time -->
    <bean id="simpleTrigger"
        class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SimpleTriggerFactoryBean">
        <property name="jobDetail" ref="myJob" />
        <property name="repeatInterval" value="15000" />
        <property name="startDelay" value="0" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Scheduler factory bean to bind,the executing code and time intervals
         together. -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
        <property name="jobDetails">
            <list>
                <ref bean="myJob" />
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="triggers">
            <list>
                <ref bean="simpleTrigger" />
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

#### File FixedDelayWorker.java

```
package e24online.corporate.cas.printer.testScheduler;

import e24online.log.E24onlineLogger;

public class FixedDelayWorker implements Worker {

    public void work() {
        String threadName = Thread.currentThread().getName();
        E24onlineLogger.sysLog.debug("   " + threadName + " has began working.");
        E24onlineLogger.sysLog.debug("working...");
        E24onlineLogger.sysLog.debug("   " + threadName + " has completed work.");
    }
}
```

**Output/Logs**

```
2014-05-05 15:06:53,462  - DEBUG [ FixedDelayWorker - work() -  9 ] -    org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#0_Worker-10 has began working.
2014-05-05 15:06:53,462  - DEBUG [ FixedDelayWorker - work() - 10 ] - working...
2014-05-05 15:06:53,462  - DEBUG [ FixedDelayWorker - work() - 11 ] -    org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#0_Worker-10 has completed work.
2014-05-05 15:06:54,881  - DEBUG [ FixedDelayWorker - work() -  9 ] -    org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#0_Worker-10 has began working.
2014-05-05 15:06:54,882  - DEBUG [ FixedDelayWorker - work() - 10 ] - working...
2014-05-05 15:06:54,882  - DEBUG [ FixedDelayWorker - work() - 11 ] -    org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#0_Worker-10 has completed work.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it might be because you are including the following line twice in your web.xml

```
<param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml</param-value>
```

once as a separate  and once for the Spring servlet definition.
This might be creating two different contexts.
I have not tested with your code...

Comment: But if I remove application context then, my application is not coming up :(

Answer (score 0):

**Your Code:**

```
<context-param> 
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

**And**

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

you are calling the **spring-servlet.xml** twice.

**My Suggestion is :**

```
   <servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>

   <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
```

**or simply**

```
<servlet>
   <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
   <servlet-class>
     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
   </servlet-class>
   <init-param>
     <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
     <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/dispatcher-config.xml</param-value>
   </init-param>
   <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>

 <servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
```

hope it helps

if you notice i didnt put any explanation because im having a hard time to explain it. i hope this codes will do.